# PyPi lead to older version of my package instead of the latest

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

So I have currently uploaded this package: https://pypi.org/project/easy-predictor/0.6.5/ main problem is that when I searched for easy-predictor (which is the name of my package) on PyPi page it displays my older version which is 0.6.3 (https://pypi.org/project/easy-predictor/). Second problem is when I tried to install the latest version of my package (0.6.5) on Command Promt by using pip, it throws this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy-predictor==0.6.5 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for easy-predictor==0.6.5
```

I've aswell updated the pip version to the latest.

How do I resolve both errors? and what causes them?.

Comment: It was released [half an hour ago](https://pypi.org/project/easy-predictor/0.6.5/#history), maybe it takes time to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check with:

```
pip install easy-predictor==
```

So without a version?

I get this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy-predictor== (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.4, 0.6.5)
```

So 0.6.5 is available in the list.